# Django design login

Tags: django, authentication

I want to design the login system
when I try entering the web and press login button
but nothing happens
please help me

this is my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNktN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5bHP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBtI2.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD9vK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your variable 'massage' has not been passed into the template as you render the template as a respone.
`variable ={'mytext' : text }`
`return render(request,'login.html', variable)`

and than you can access them in your login html page using jinja templating language. for example variables can be accessed as:

`<h1> hello {{mytext}} </h1>`

Comment: thank you, your suggestion help about  massage of question

Comment: if it helped you, give my answer an upvote.